# Parsing XML from rest api in swift

Tags: ios, xml, swift

I'm trying to parse xml data from a rest api which uses POST method, but the parsing fails, when I run it it prints:

> Optional("result><[CDATA[101]]>")
>   parse failure!

```
class MyTableTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSXMLParserDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
var parser = NSXMLParser()
var posts = NSMutableArray()
var elements = NSMutableDictionary()
var strXMLData:String = ""
var currentElement:String = ""
var passData:Bool=false
var passName:Bool=false
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getData()

}

func getData() {
    let postEndpoint: String = "http://www.iaa.edu.jo/load/iaa/news"
    let url = NSURL(string: postEndpoint)!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { ( data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        guard let realResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where
            realResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                print("Not a 200 response")
                return
        }
        self.posts = []
        let newStr = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print(newStr)

        self.parser = NSXMLParser(data: data!)
        self.parser.delegate = self
        self.parser.parse()
        let success:Bool = self.parser.parse()

        if success {
            print("parse success!")

            print(self.strXMLData)

        } else {
            print("parse failure!")
        }


    }).resume()

}
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
    currentElement=elementName
    if(elementName=="page" )
    {
        passData=true;
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    currentElement="";
    if(elementName=="page")
    {
        passData=false;
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    if(passData){
        strXMLData=strXMLData+"\n\n"+string
          print(string)
    }

}


func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: NSError) {
    NSLog("failure error: %@", parseError)
}
```

I couldnt figure out what's wrong, Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error is most likely in your xml file. Please include an example of the xml in the question.

Comment: @PhilB Thank you :) I fixed it, the problem was that I was supposed to pass the parameters in the request HTTPBody.